# Problema en código devuelve mal sumas par e impar por separado

Tags: c

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio de práctica en el que se me pedía esto:

**Plantee e implemente un programa en Lenguaje C que reciba números enteros
por teclado y al terminar indique cuánto vale la suma de los números pares y los
impares por separado. La entrada de números terminará cuando se introduzca
un cero.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

typedef int pares[MAX], impares[MAX];

void pedir(pares par, impares impar);

void ejecutar(const pares par,const impares impar);

int main() {
    pares pares1;
    impares impares1;
    pedir(pares1, impares1);
    ejecutar(pares1, impares1);
}

void pedir(pares par, impares impar) {
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        printf("Introduce un numero entero:");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if ((a % 2) == 0)par[i] = a;
        if ((a % 2) != 0)impar[i] = a;
        if (a == 0)return;
    }
}

void ejecutar(const pares par,const impares impar) {
    int sumaPAR = 0, sumaIMPAR = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        sumaPAR = sumaPAR + par[i];
        sumaIMPAR = sumaIMPAR + impar[i];
    }
    printf("La suma de los pares es: %d\n", sumaPAR);
    printf("La suma de los impares es: %d\n", sumaIMPAR);
}
```

Este código me devuelve valores como:

```
Introduce un numero entero:2
Introduce un numero entero:1
Introduce un numero entero:0
La suma de los pares es: -1987168079
La suma de los impares es: -398327378

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Le he estado dando vueltas y no encuentro el fallo, alguien me puede iluminar? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes porque estás rellenando dos arrays distintos con el mismo subíndice, me explico:

Imagina que meter 3 números pares y uno impar. Bien, en el `for` de rellenar los valores tendrás los 3 primeros elementos del array par bien, pero luego el subíndice vale 4 y lo almacenas en el array de impares. Así que tienes dos arrays, el de par podemos decir que relleno con información ‘buena’ pero el array de impares las 3 primeras posiciones tienes basura y en el cuarto elemento el número que has introducido.

Cuando haces la suma de los elementos estás sumando información que no sabes cuál es, es decir, basura, porque tampoco inicializas los arrays mediante la instrucción `array = {0};`.

**SOLUCION:** utiliza dos bucles `for` distintos tanto para rellenar los arrays como para mostrarlos, obviamente con subíndices distintos, de ese modo si insertas 3 números pares y 1 impar pues solo sumarás 3 números para la suma par y 1 suma para la suma de impares.

Comment: Gracias :D tu explicación me resolvió el problema